# python threading, admin and client

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been doing some development on this project. achieving multiple connections for the client to the sever. However i am now trying to implement the admin connections through a different port number. Which will not conflict the operation to the client. I changed it so that it calls the function which then calls the operations for which the client or admin which then plays the game or admin controls. how do i call the port number to that function so it runs that code? which calls the game or admin controls? (new to coding) however i feel i need to call them at the bottom of the script....

```
`# Server
  import socket
  import math
  import random
  import re
  import threading

 #TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
 #TCP_PORT = 4001
 #s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 #s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
 #s.listen(5)
 #print("Waiting...")
 #connection check


 def handle_ClientPort(port): # porting for client through threading
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",port))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        (c,a) = s.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target = handle_client, args = (c,a))
        t.start()


def handle_AdminPort(port): #proting for adminm connection through threading
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1",port))
    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        (c,a) = s.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target = Admin_client, args = (c,a))
        t.start()



def handle_Admin(c,a): #function for admin controls
    while True:
            text = c.recv(80).decode()

            if text == 'Who':
                    c.send("who has workd".encode()) 

            elif text == 'Hello':
                    c.send('Admin-Greetings'.encode())
            else:
                  c.send('please use the correct admin commands'.encode())
            return

def handle_client(c,a): #This works(game)

    def within(vaule,goal,n):
            if abs(goal - vaule)<= n:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    while True:
            rmd = random.randrange(0,30)
            print('The random number is',rmd) # radom number

            hello = c.recv(78).decode()

            if hello == "Hello\r\n":
                    c.send('Greetings\r\n'.encode())
            else:       
                    c.send('ERROR\r\n'.encode())
            game = c.recv(80).decode()

            if game == "Game\r\n":
                    c.send('Ready\r\n'.encode())

            else:
                    c.send('ERROR\r\n'.encode()) # change this

            # hand shake communcation works


            while True:
                    geuss = re.findall('\d+',c.recv(80).decode())
                    print(geuss)
                    geuss1 = int(''.join(map(str,geuss)))
                    print(geuss1)
                    checker = within(geuss1,rmd,2)

                    if geuss1 == rmd:
                        c.send("Correct\r\n".encode())
                        c.close()
                        return
                    elif checker == True:
                        c.send("Close\r\n".encode())
                    else:
                        c.send("Far\r\n".encode())

    c.close()
    return





admin = 4001
client = 4000


#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,)
#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,)
```

Comment: Ah I have solved the problem!, i needed to put this at the bottom. s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,)
o = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,)
#admin = 4001
#client = 4000

c = threading.Thread(target = handle_Port, args = (4000,))
c.start()

a = threading.Thread(target = handle_Port2, args = (4001,))
a.start()